# SAPUI5 Component Metadata rootView Parameter for JSONView

Tags: json, components, rootview, sapui5

Has anyone been able to specify a JSON view in the `rootView` parameter in the metadata of SAPUI5(or OPENUI5) component. My ultimate goal is to implement something similiar to this "Best Practices" demo app using JSON views.

In the "Application Best Practices" UI5 demo app, the component.js file contains a metadata parameter: `rootView: "sap.ui.demo.tdg.view.App"` which points to an XML view of the same name that is declared as follows:

```
<mvc:View
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  displayBlock="true"
  xmlns="sap.m">
  <SplitApp id="idAppControl" />
</mvc:View>
```

Also, the router configuration contains `viewType : "XML"`.

I have seen no examples in which a JSON view is specified in the `rootView` parameter, but have seen no documentation that states this parameter only works with XML views. I myself had no luck with creation the following App.view.json file:

```
{
"Type": "sap.ui.core.mvc.JSONView",
"controllerName": "sap.ui.demo.tdg.view.App",
"content": [
    {
      "Type": "sap.m.SplitApp",
      "id": "idAppControl" /*,
    }
  ]
}
```

and changing the `viewType : "JSON"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using a Component.js, then in the createContent method, you can return a root view of any type. For example, I have similar metadata config to you, found in my Component.js file.

In the same file, I have a function createContent, which is called on Component initialisation, and in this method, I return a JS type view. There's no reason you couldn't return a JSON view instead. So, change this parameter type to that of your choosing, i.e. JSON.

```
jQuery.sap.declare("my.app.Component");
jQuery.sap.require("my.app.MyRouter");

sap.ui.core.UIComponent.extend("my.app.Component",{
    metadata : {
        dependencies : {
            libs : [ "sap.m", "sap.ui.layout" ],
            components : []
        },
        rootView : "my.app.view.App",
       etc...
    },
    ...
    createContent : function() {

        // create root view
        var oView = sap.ui.view({
            id : "idApp",
            viewName : "view.App",
            type : "JSON", // <-- change this to JSON
            viewData : {
                component : this
            }
        });

        // done
        return oView;
    }
});
```

Cheers